# Extract table as JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a code which parses a website. Now I need to extract a specific table from the webpage. My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pricing </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js"></script>
<script>
//$(function(){
      function requestCrossDomain(site, callback) {
          if (!site) {
              alert('No site was passed.');
              return false;
          }
          var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';
          $.getJSON(yql, cbFunc);
          function cbFunc(data) {
              if (data.results[0]) {
                  data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');
                      window[callback](data);
              } else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
          }
      }
      //$('#test').click(function(){
          var url = 'https://www.emcsg.com/marketdata/priceinformation';

          requestCrossDomain(url, 'someFunction');



function someFunction(results){
    console.log(results);
    $('#loadedContent').css("display","").html(results);  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="loadedContent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The webpage that is parsed is https://www.emcsg.com/marketdata/priceinformation

The webpage has a few tables, but I need to extract a specific table "view 72 periods". I inspected the page, the table is nested inside various classes. Is there a simple way to extract the table?

Comment: please add example of `data` that is passed to cbFunc to the end of your question

Comment: Also: why do you need the yahoo thing? Why don't you request the page directly, if anyway you get the whole html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
var html = $(results);
var table = html.find(".view72PeriodsWrapper");
```

or as you changed your mind in the comment:

```
var table = html.find(".realtimeTableContainer");
```

See in action:

```js
//$(function(){
      function requestCrossDomain(site, callback) {
          if (!site) {
              alert('No site was passed.');
              return false;
          }
          var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';
          $.getJSON(yql, cbFunc);
          function cbFunc(data) {
              if (data.results[0]) {
                  data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');
                      window[callback](data);
              } else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
          }
      }
      //$('#test').click(function(){
          var url = 'https://www.emcsg.com/marketdata/priceinformation';

          requestCrossDomain(url, 'someFunction');



function someFunction(results){
    var html = $(results);
    var table = html.find(".realtimeTableContainer");
    $('#loadedContent').css("display","").html(table);  
}
```

```css
.realtimeTableHeaderContainer{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js"></script-->
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="loadedContent"></div>
```

Comment: This was helpful. but is there a way to eliminate the header of the table and the lines below the data? I only need the data. thanks. and sorry the question might be silly, but im a newbie and i really dont know

Comment: yes, though that was not the question. See my updated answer